# Does anyone know what set these Mega Bloks grey parts are from?

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

My son bought some loose Mega Bloks in the UK and we are trying to identify what sets these parts could be from.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The part with the suctioncup and the cannon part are from Skylanders Giants

[image]
Battle portals

[image]
Zeppelin Airship Assault